# Given a flight number, how can one know the max capacity & number of batteries one may have in carry-on luggage, without contacting airline companies?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage, batteries

Given a flight number, how can one know the maximum capacity (mAh or Wh) and number of external batteries one may have in one's carry-on luggage, without having to contact the airline company or search through their websites?

[Example of external batteries, a.k.a. power banks](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B07TSHW85D/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1):

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "external" batteries?

Comment: @Doc Thanks for the feedback, I've edited the question to clarify it.

Comment: You want to ask a question, but you don't want to ask the people best placed to answer - the people who would know. That's just perverse!

Comment: If you do not want to do research you can always go to the safe option, take non.

Comment: The issue with having to contact the airline company or search through their websites. That's why I'm looking for a faster option to get the information.

Answer (score 2):

I think a general answer is not possible. What you can take aboard as carry-on will depend upon the airline's rules, how those rules are enforced (or not) by the airline, as well as the rules and actions of airport security at that particular airport, that particular time, and those particular security workers.

Without talking to the airline directly, you're left with the airline's web statements, whatever information you can discover about or from the security processes at that airport, and prior travelers' reports and comments.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping some website would aggregate the information from different airline companies.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the airline says otherwise (for instance, on their website, boarding passes, tickets...), it is most likely they apply the [IATA guidelines](https://www.iata.org/contentassets/6fea26dd84d24b26a7a1fd5788561d6e/passenger-lithium-battery.pdf).

Power banks are considered as spare batteries: you can carry up to 20 with a capacity of less than 100 Wh each in your carry-on luggage. Beyond that it becomes more complex.

Comment: Powerbanks are NOT considered spare batteries. Which is good, because spare batteries are NOT permitted in checked baggage, but powerbanks sometimes are (depending on the country/airline involved, thus the root of this question)

Comment: @Doc From the linked document: "Articles containing lithium cells or batteries, the primary purpose of which is to provide power to another device, e.g. power banks, are considered as spare batteries and are restricted to carry-on baggage only."

Comment: @Doc TSA regulations are slightly different (no limit on spare batteries in carry-on), but the same limits in terms of capacity and checked luggage apply, and "[This also includes external battery chargers (portable rechargers) containing a lithium ion battery.](https://www.faa.gov/hazmat/packsafe/more_info/?hazmat=7)"